# Matplotlib yielding different results in jupyter and python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm trying to replicate in Python the exact same figure previously generated in Jupyter, but the same code is generating figures with different aspect ratios and sizes.

The code below saves 600x400 image in Jupyter but 640x480 in Python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(matplotlib.get_backend())
y = np.array([1,2,3,4])
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.plot(y)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('1234_py.png', dpi=100)
```

The terminal output is (windows subsystem for linux):

```
   $ python stckvflw.py 
   module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline
   Figure(640x480)
```

The 640x480 image below is produced:

[simple plot python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S00ze.png)

The same code running in jupyter produce a 600x400 image below

[simple plot jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMVex.png)

I modified matploblib backend in the terminal to match the backend used in jupyter by default, using the command below:

```
     export MPLBACKEND="module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline"
```

Changing the backend didn't affect the saved image.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672227/pyplot-subplots-different-behavior-in-python-and-jupyter-notebook) your issue.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem!